# Solve the PDE $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=x$ using Laplace transform in $t$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Using Laplace transform in $t$, or otherwise, solve the equation for $u$:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=x$$

in the region: $x$ > 0, $t$ > 0, 
subject to the boundary condition $u$(0,t) = 0 and 
to the initial condition $u$(x,0)=$f$(x)

Comment: I have changed the equation to a PDE as was mentioned parenthetically. Please make sure I have not changed your intended question.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method of characteristics**

On any line $\mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{d}t$ (that is, $x=x_0+t$), we get
$$
\mathrm{d}u=\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}t+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}x=x\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}
$$
Integrating, we get
$$
u(x,x-x_0)=\frac12x^2+v(x_0)\tag{2}
$$
or
$$
u(x,t)=\frac12x^2+v(x-t)\tag{3}
$$
for any differentiable function $v$.

---

**Initial Conditions**

The two conditions meet at $(0,0)$. The characteristic that passes through this point is $x=t$.

For $x\le t$, we use the initial condition $u(0,t)=0$, which means 
$$
\begin{align}
v(0-t)
&=u(0,t)-\frac12\cdot0^2\\
&=0\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
For $t\gt x$, we use the initial condition $u(x,0)=f(x)$, which means
$$
\begin{align}
v(x-0)
&=u(x,0)-\frac12x^2\\
&=f(x)-\frac12x^2\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
v(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{}
0&\text{if }x\le0\\
f(x)-\frac12x^2&\text{if }x\gt0
\end{array}\right.\tag{6}
$$
and we plug $(6)$ into $(3)$.

Comment: This looks good, but I am having trouble applying the initial and boundary condition to the problem that I just added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\bracks{%
\partiald{{\rm u}\pars{x,t}}{t} + \partiald{{\rm u}\pars{x,t}}{x}}\expo{-st}
\,\dd t & = \int_{0}^{\infty}x\expo{-st}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]
\imp -\ \overbrace{{\rm u}\pars{x,0}}^{\ds{=\ {\rm f}\pars{x}}}\ + s\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm u}\pars{x,t}\expo{-st}\,\dd t}
^{\ds{\equiv\ \hat{\rm u}\pars{x,s}}}\ + \partiald{}{x}\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm u}\pars{x,t}\expo{-st}\,\dd t}^{\ds{\equiv\ \hat{\rm u}\pars{x,s}}}\ & =\ {x \over s}
\end{align}

Then,
$$
\pars{\partiald{}{x} + s}\hat{\rm u}\pars{x,s} = {x \over s} + {\rm f}\pars{x}
\quad\imp\quad
\partiald{\bracks{\expo{sx}\hat{\rm u}\pars{x,s}}}{x} =
{x \over s}\,\expo{sx} + {\rm f}\pars{x}\expo{sx}
$$

$$
\expo{sx}\hat{\rm u}\pars{x,s}\ -\ \overbrace{\hat{\rm u}\pars{0,s}}^{\ds{=\ 0}} =
{1 \over s}\,{1 + \expo{sx}\pars{sx - 1} \over s^{2}} + \int_{0}^{x}
{\rm f}\pars{x'}\expo{sx'}\,\dd x'
$$

$$
\hat{\rm u}\pars{x,s} = \
{\expo{-sx} + sx - 1 \over s^{3}} + \expo{-sx}\int_{0}^{x}
{\rm f}\pars{x'}\expo{sx'}\,\dd x'
$$

---

With $t > 0$:

\begin{align}
{\rm u}\pars{x,t} & =
\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}
{\expo{s\pars{t - x}} \over s^{3}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} +
x\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}
{\expo{st} \over s^{2}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} -
\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}
{\expo{st} \over s^{3}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic} + \mbox{}
\\[3mm] & \int_{0}^{x}
{\rm f}\pars{x'}\bracks{%
\int_{0^{+}\ -\ \infty\ic}^{0^{+}\ +\ \infty\ic}\expo{s\pars{x' + t - x}}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}}\,\dd x'
\\[5mm] & = \Theta\pars{t - x}\,\half\pars{t - x}^{2} + xt - \half\,t^{2} +
\int_{0}^{x}{\rm f}\pars{x'}\delta\pars{x' + t - x}\,\dd x'
\\[3mm] & = \Theta\pars{t - x}\,\half\pars{t - x}^{2} + xt - \half\,t^{2} +
\Theta\pars{x - t}{\rm f}\pars{x - t}
\end{align}

---

---

$$
\mbox{With}\ x > 0\ \mbox{and}\ t > 0:\qquad
{\rm u}\pars{x,t} =
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lcrcl}
\half\,x^{2} & \mbox{if} & x & < & t
\\
xt - \half\,t^{2} + {\rm f}\pars{x - t} & \mbox{if} & x & > & t
\end{array}\right.
$$